# php: if (file_exists($file)) returns true for some files, false for others

Tags: php, if-statement, file-exists

i'm stumped. i'm putting together a script to take PATH_INFO from a URL and use that to send files from a particular directory on the server.

on the server:

```
ll /path/to/directory/with/my/files/
total 7195210
-rwxrwx--- 1 user group  716852833 May 11 15:17 file1.7z
-rwxrwx--- 1 user group 1000509440 May 11 15:31 file2.cxarchive
-rwxrwx--- 1 user group 5878056960 May 11 17:32 file3.ISO
```

i have an `if (file_exists($file)` block in my code, and it works for file1 and file2, but file3, **that's in the exact same location**, it triggers the else statement, indicating that PHP thinks that file doesn't exist.

```
<?php
//get file name from URL, trim leading slash.
$filename = ltrim($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], "/");

//sanitize the filename
if(preg_match('/\.\.|[<>&~;`\/$]/', $filename)) {
    trigger_error("Invalid path '$filename' attempted by $user");
    show_error();
}

//prepend my files directory to the filename.
$file = '/path/to/directory/with/my/files/' . $filename;

//send file
if (file_exists($file)) {
    echo '<pre>The file '; print_r($file); echo ' exists.</pre>';
    header('X-Sendfile: $file');
    exit;
} else {
    echo '<pre>the file does not exist?</pre>';
    show_error();
}

?>
```

so if i browse to the following URLs on my server:

https://my.server.com/script.php/file1.7z

The file file1.7z exists.

https://my.server.com/script.php/file2.cxarchive

The file file2.cxarchive exists.

https://my.server.com/script.php/file3.ISO

The file does not exist?

a bunch of testing results in the likely culprit being that the file is large. i get that with sending files memory limits are an issue, but how do i get PHP to see that this (large) file exists?

Comment: Are you adding this file? Sometimes I've had issues where you have to clear the stat cache using: http://php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php but I can't say that would be your issue.

Comment: Where are you hosting your website? If it's hosted on a UNIX machine, files are case-sensitive. If you can't navigate there **manually**, it's a good indication that you've probably actually uploaded a file with a differently-cased file extension.

Comment: `Because PHP's integer type is signed and many platforms use 32bit integers, some filesystem functions may return unexpected results for files which are larger than 2GB.` -http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php So the < 2 GB files don't have a problem and your 5GB gives you issues.

Comment: `header('X-Sendfile: $file');` should be `header("X-Sendfile: $file");`

Comment: it may emit an E_WARNING with some explanation

Comment: i think @user3783243 hit the nail on the head. i read that page specifically looking for an issue, and apparently read right over that note. (i think i probably got hung up on whether it was the red note about safe mode restrictions.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on @user3783243's comment above:

> Because PHP's integer type is signed and many platforms use 32bit integers, some filesystem functions may return unexpected results for files which are larger than 2GB.
>
> -https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

so i wrote my own file_exists function without that limitation (based on a [comment on that page](https://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php#103436)):

```
function fileExists($file){
return (@fopen($file,"r")==true);
}
```

then, inserting it into the code:

```
//send file
if (fileExists($file)) {    //remove underscore, cap E
echo '<pre>The file '; print_r($file); echo ' exists.</pre>';
header("X-Sendfile: $file");    //fixed, thanks @jamie
exit;
} else {
echo '<pre>the file does not exist?</pre>';
show_error();
}
```

success! files that exist work (even big ones), files that do not run show_error().